# How to store a phone number (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, phone-number

I want to store a user's phone number in my model but don't know which format to store it in.

What's the best practice when it comes to storing phone numbers and how can it be processed easily via a registration form (and through serializers etc...)? I am new to Django so I need some advice concerning this.

Comment: I suggest that you use a library, like [**`django-phonenumber-field`**](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field)

Comment: I did actually. However, I ran into many errors like: **Can't convert int to PhoneNumber** and a few more.

Comment: well how did you come up with storing an `int` as a phone number in the first place?

Comment: check my answer, and never store phone number as integers. They can contain alphanumeric characters as well. And as principle if you dont use a number-like thing on a mathematical equatiton, that should be string not int.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex validator. You dont need 3rd party libs.

```
# models.py
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

# this is your user model
class YourUser(AbstractUser):

    # error message when a wrong format entered
    phone_message = 'Phone number must be entered in the format: 05999999999' 

     # your desired format 
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(
        regex=r'^(05)\d{9}$',
        message=phone_message
    )

    # finally, your phone number field
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=60,
                             null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you explain what this means: **r'^(05)\d{9}$'** ?

Comment: starts with "05" and continues with {nine} (d)igits

Comment: you can check here for a cheat-sheet https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [**django-phonenumber-field**](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field) package to easily handle phone numbers.